# How to trigger s3 copy cli copy events in cdk python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

What `EventType` should I use? Tried all CREATED properties e.g. `OBJECT_CREATED_PUT` yet can't catch any event.

`$ aws s3 cp ./testFile.txt s3://....` >> CloudWatch > log > Received event: {}

app.py

```py
from aws_cdk import aws_s3 as _s3

output_s3 = _s3.Bucket(self,
                       "output_s3",
                       removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
                       auto_delete_objects=True)

# allows the instance to read/write files
output_s3.grant_read_write(instance)

# create s3 notification for lambda function
notification = aws_s3_notifications.LambdaDestination(function)

output_s3.add_event_notification(
    _s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED_COMPLETE_MULTIPART_UPLOAD,
    notification)

output_s3.add_event_notification(_s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED_PUT,
                                 notification)
```

lambda_handler.py

```py
import json

def main(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    return json.dumps(event, indent=2)
```

Comment: So does the lambda execute at all?

Comment: @gshpychka Yes. With the mentioned emtpy event though.

Comment: What if you try `print(event)`? What does your function definition look like? To be clear, your question is not about triggering an event (it does trigger), it's about the event being empty when it triggers.